# How can I modify a python regular expression to check whether string elements exist in another string?

Tags: python, pandas, regex, string, python-regex

I know a similar question has been asked by me but wanted to modify it a bit to account for a new specific use case.

I have a string such as `SIT,UAT` call it `a1, a2` where `a1` and `a2` can be any sequence of characters separated by a `,`. There can also be any number of unique elements such as an `a3` and `a4`. These `a1` and `a2` (up to `aN`) elements will only ever occur once in each `a1, a2` combination.

I need a python regex that will allow me to check whether only (`SIT` and `UAT`) exist in a particular string separated by `,` if there is more than 1 element in the inputted list.

Scenarios:

Input 1: `SIT,UAT`

1. `SIT,UAT` - should match with regex
2. `UAT,SIT` - should match with regex
3. `SIT` - should fail as both SIT and UAT not present together
4. `UAT` - should fail as both SIT and UAT not present together
5. `TRA,SIT,UAT` - should fail as only SIT and UAT must be present together with no other elements as TRA was not provided in the input list

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it is a better use case for a proper function than trying to hack it in a regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression you probably want to use here is:

```
^(?:SIT,UAT|UAT,SIT)$
```

Sample Pandas code:

```py
def valid(env1, env2):
    pat = r'^(?:' + env1 + r',' + env2 + r'|' + env2 + r',' + env1 + r')$'
    return df["col"].str.contains(pat, regex=True)
```

If you need to cater to more than two expected CSV values, then regex might not scale nicely.  In that case, I would suggest splitting the input on comma and then using the base string functions:

```py
inp = "TST,SIT,UAT,PROD"
vals = inp.split(",")
allowed = ["SIT", "UAT"]
output = all(p in allowed for p in vals)
print(output)  # False, because the input has TST and PROD
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't generalize easily to more than 4 tokens, as the regexp needs to have all the permutations and the size grows rapidly.

Comment: I was just about to ask, what would be the best way to generalize this for n elements, a1,a2,a3? Should I have python create all the permutations and input them as a string to this regex? Might be quite a long string if there were many elements.

Comment: Check the updated answer for a generalization of checking for any two environments dynamically.

Comment: @Tim, The question asks how to check for any number of elements dynamically. There could be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 elements separated by commas. How could I tweak your answer to get me there?

Comment: Perhaps I will have to forcibly sort the input string and only allow the regex to check for SIT,UAT only instead of all permutations.

Comment: I have added a string splitting option which should scale better than regex.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, this is an option to solve it. Unless your match values are fixed to be `SIT,UAT` or only a few known values, I'd rather suggest you to not got with regex and solve it by splitting the list.

```
def verify(input, match):
    matchList = list(sorted(match.split(',')))
    inputList = list(sorted(input.split(',')))
    return inputList == matchList

match = "SIT,UAT"
print(verify("SIT,UAT", match))     # true
print(verify("UAT,SIT", match))     # true
print(verify("SIT", match))         # false
print(verify("UAT", match))         # false
print(verify("TRA,SIT,UAT", match)) # false
```

The above assumes nothing about your `match` string. If you know that repeats don't matter, you could use `set` comparison instead of `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the aforementioned pattern:

```txt
pattern = ^(?=^(SIT,UAT)|(UAT,SIT)$)(?!(.*?,(?!SIT|UAT))+).*
```

- `(?=^(SIT,UAT)|(UAT,SIT)$)` is used to check if string matches either SIT,UAT or UAT,SIT...
- `(?!(.*?,(?!SIT|UAT))+)` is used to check that the string does not match any element besides SIT & UAT

Hope this helps.